# How to convert the date format in excel csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to plot a candlestick graphs with matplotlib python. However, I couldn't get the result because of the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

I am using excel csv file as data,the date format in csv is 23/1/2019. How can I convert it to floating numbers?

```
file_name = 'SGDMYR.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

d = df.Date
o = df.Open
h = df.High
l = df.Low
c = df.Close

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0))

x = 0
y = len(d)
ohlc = []

while x < y:
    append_me = d[x],o[x],h[x],l[x],c[x]
    ohlc.append(append_me)
    x+=1

mf.candlestick_ohlc(ax1, ohlc, width=0.4, colorup='#77d879', colordown='#db3f3f')

for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(45)

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
    ax1.grid(True)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add details about the error, otherwise the community will also be wondering what's going wrong with your code (i.e. we can only guess without the details)

Comment: @Graham Thanks for your reminding. I have edited my question.

Comment: @JordanChoo show **complete** message error and show the content of SGDMYR.csv file